# How to style a Dashed Range Slider with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, range

I would like to build custom styled range slider with a dashed line, where every point value is a gap in a line. Similarly to how it looks here: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/slider
I was able to style all part of the slider except a line that should be dashed.
Is it possible to add a dashed line as a pseudo element after the slider line and change the number of dashed items depending on the slider max value only by using CSS or the only way to do it is by updating the gradient for every slider on initialization with JS?

Comment: Standard `input` elements doesn't support pseudo, but wrap it in e.g. a `div` and setup a pseudo on that.

Comment: Ok, I got that. But is it possible to change the number of dashes in the line gradient dynamically? Smth. similar to content: attr(data-val)

Comment: Dashed line with pseudo: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/ZxOzLy
Dashed line with border-right: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/XEKrgV

I didn't get the second point with the value of lines...

Comment: No, you can't use `CSS attr()` to control the amount of dashes. For that you might want to use script or media query.